# Python throws exception on import using pgu with pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pgu

When I `from pgu import pgu as pgui` I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/pyspace/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from simulator.game import Game
  File "C:\path\pyspace\simulator\game.py", line 5, in <module>
    from simulator.guis.simulategui import SimulateGUI
  File "C:\path\pyspace\simulator\guis\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from simulator.guis.simulategui import SimulateGUI
  File "C:\path\pyspace\simulator\guis\simulategui.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pgu import gui as pgui
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pgu\gui\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .container import Container
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pgu\gui\container.py", line 57
    except StyleError,e:
```

when I open the `...\gui\container.py` with pycharm there is an error that tells me that `Python version 3.5 does not support this syntax`.  The syntax in `container.py` in `pgu` is as follows:

```
        try:
            # This hack isn't perfect and so it's not enabled by default, but only by
            # themes that explicitly request it.
            alpha = pguglobals.app.theme.getstyle("pgu", "", "themealpha")
        except StyleError,e:
            alpha = False
```

I am running python 3.5.1 with pygame 1.9.2a0 and pgu 0.18.  Do I need to install a different version of pgu or different version of a GUI manager for pygame altogether, or is there a simple way to solve this?  I'm assuming I get to install a different GUI manager; but was hoping that there is a simple fix to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like pgu is still using Python 2.7 exception handling. You could change your local copy to read

```
except StyleError as e:
```

but that would still have to be sent upstream if you're redistributing the code.

Comment: If it isn't Python 3 friendly, there could be several other non-py3 lines in there that will cause problems. It would be best to actually see if there is a version that is py-3 friendly.

Comment: :( http://pygame.org/project-PGU+-+Phil's+pyGame+Utilities-108-.html says that it is python 3 compatible.  I suppose I have to try something else then.

Comment: It could be Python 3.x with x < 5 friendly — I don't remember when that syntax got removed. As idjaw says, it might have other similar syntax not working around it.